# Use bootstrap dropdown menu with month labels within Yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I can see how to create dropdown menu in bootstrap, but within context of Yii2's `menuItems[]`, I'm unsure of the syntax.

I need a menu item with dropdowns for the current month (it should work it out dynamically ofcourse), and the prior 2 or 3 months.
Ie, ListMenu -> March -> Feb -> Jan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this code will work for you the same as mine. But to give you some guide, add the following code under $menuItems[] which will be seen under views/layouts/main.php.

```
['label' => 'Month', 'url' => ['product/index'], 'items' => [
                ['label' => 'January', 'url' => ['site/january', 'tag' => 'new']],
                ['label' => 'February', 'url' => ['site/february', 'tag' => 'popular']],
                ['label' => 'March', 'url' => ['site/march', 'tag' => 'popular']],
]],
```

Hope this code will work! :)

Comment: thx but I dont want to explicitly say "January" etc, I want it to find it from the current `date`, then work backwards and get the last 2/3 months